# Filling a Django admin form from an API request

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am currently learning Django (v2.1) and I am wondering what is the best way to populate an admin form from an API request. For example, if I am adding a new user in the admin and I enter a "zip code/postcode", the system should do a call to a remote address lookup API and based on the result, should populate the rest of the address fields in the admin form.

How do I add a button in the admin section next to the "zip code" field and how do I link that button to an action to fill the other fields? 
Do I use JS or do I extend an admin template or do I override an admin view?
Links to example code and/or docs would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve that would, probably be extending admin template with button and some javascript code which would call this remote address API and set values of form fields.

Here about template overriding:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I don't think I can call the API directly from the Javascript since it requires a username/password.

Comment: Other way, you can ask in form only for zip code, and then fill address fields on server side. But personally I don't think implementing something like that would be really useful.